# What is the warning call for falling rocks in your area?

Tags: safety, climbing, terminology, caving

I was inspired by the question ["What should one do when climbing if someone above you yells ROCK?"](/q/15717) to ask what the equivalents are around the world.

So, **what would I shout to warn someone below me of falling rocks?**

Equivalently, **what word should I react to when I hear it shouted?**

I've created an answer as a Community Wiki to accumulate knowledge from everyone; please contribute to that.

Comment: [The Climbing Dictionary](http://www-dft.ts.infn.it/~esmargia/mountain/climbing_dict.html) has a few. British: "Below", "beware"; German "Stein"; French "Pierre", "Caillou"; Swedish "Sten".

Comment: This question in general is interesting for climbers but it's not really fitting in the scope of Stackexchange. Questions which generate list-type answers aren't prefered here. Similar is [this](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/7551/1000-names-for-snow) one which was closed too. I am sorry but I vote to close therefore.

Comment: I think this is a very useful question. Lets protect it and make one community answer and everyone contributes there.

Comment: This is the kind of question whose answer could be very helpful.  The alternative is to have dozens of more specific questions - would that be a better resource?  I've made my answer a CW as that is better than one answer per region and can be curated for consistency, but I'm open to suggestions that would improve this and make it a valuable contribution to [outdoors.se].

Comment: @imsodin Good idea, voted to reopen then :)

Comment: When climbing in an international setting, I shout out all variations I know, "Sten!, Rock!, Stein!" etc Similar if I'm throwing a rope. "Rep!, Seil!, Tau!, Seil!"

Comment: Really, @Guran?  Do you manage them all before the rock lands?!

Comment: It depends, naturally. If I kick out a rock on a single pitch climb no. But on multi pitch, or if I break a hold, but still have it in my hand, definitely.

Comment: @Guran https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OnsyQh0FfoM :^)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## North America

### English Canada / United States

> "**ROCK!**" (pronounced /rɒk/)

### French Canada

> "**ROCHE!**" (pronounced /ʁɔʃ/)

---

## Europe

### European Alps

> "**CAILLOU !**" (pronounced /ka.ju/)

It's French but also sometimes used by non-francophone climbers and hikers in the Alps.  This word is used to warn when a hiker (or a goat!) up the trail loosens a rock that crosses the trail lower down. Fun fact: Literally it means pebble.

> "**STEIN!**" (pronounced /ʃtaɪn/)

Used in German speaking regions. Exact pronunciation varies in between regions due to dialects, but should be recognisably similar.

### Great Britain

> "**BELOW!**" (pronounced /bɪˈləʊ/)

Used in climbing and in caving; amongst others (e.g. scramblers), knowledge of it is variable.

### Sweden

> "**STEN!**" (pronounced /ste:n/)

Mainly used in climbing and caving.

---

## Asia

### India

> "**Loose rock!**"

and/or

> "**Watch out!**"